# Cloud Endpoints + AngularJS authentication without gapi

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using angular+cloud endpoints in a project, and I would like to keep it angular-y by using promises (which isn't compatible with cloud endpoints js library [as written here](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/angularjs-cloud-endpoints-recipe-for-building-modern-web-applications)). I managed to do that by calling the api with $http.

Example

```
$http.get("/_ah/api/myapi/v1/mypath").success(function(data){
    //edited for clarity
}).error(function () {
    //edited for clarity
});
```

Which works well.

But when I try to use the User parameter in my api Methods (I want to have the user in my endpoint), I find myself needing to use OAuth authentication (as the usual web.xml security constraint doesn't work with cloud endpoints).

web.xml (security constraint)

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Endpoint example (java)

```
public Person getMyself(User user) throws OAuthRequestException {
    // edited for clarity
    return person;
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to authenticate api calls made with angular's $http or do I really have to use the google's endpoint js library (gapi)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the login flow as described at [GCloud Blog](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/angularjs-cloud-endpoints-recipe-for-building-modern-web-applications/) and [GitHub Example](https://github.com/Sfeir/hello-world-oauth2-endpoints-angularjs)

You'll get the Access Token with:

```
var token = gapi.auth.getToken();
```

Then you can call the `$http` function as follows:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: PATH/getMyself, headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}});
```

Backend:

```
public Person getMyself(User user) throws OAuthRequestException {
    // edited for clarity
    return person;
}
```